# Java: Implementing a drawable class

Tags: java, graphics, implementation, maze

I'm trying to make a maze game in Java.

The Explorer class represents the user, and the DrawableExplorer is the code that graphically represents the user. DrawableExplorer implements the Drawable interface which contains:

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;

    public abstract interface Drawable
    {
      public abstract void draw(Graphics paramGraphics);
    }
```

this compiles successfully however, I cannot figure out why my DrawableExplorer class isn't:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    public class DrawableExplorer extends Explorer implements Drawable

{

    public DrawableExpolorer(Square location, Maze maze, String name)
        {
            public void draw(Graphics g)
                {
                    Square location = location();
                    get.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g.fillOval(loc.x() + 10, loc.y() + 10, 30, 30);

                }
        }
}
```

It's asking for a return type but isn't my method void?

The compiler error message says "invalid method declaration; return type required"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare the class as:

```
public class DrawableExplorer extends Explorer implements Drawable
```

i.e. The `extends` clause has to come **before** the `implements` clause.

The other error is that you've declared your `draw` method within the body of the constructor for `DrawableExplorer`.  Given that you've defined a constructor that takes three arguments you would typically want to process these within the constructor body (you currently ignore them); e.g. by assigning them to instance variables.

Comment: Can you post the compile error in your original question along with the updated code?  Also, I've edited my answer to highlight a second error.

Comment: The compiler error message says "invalid method declaration; return type required"

Comment: The constructor spelling is incorrect: "DrawableExpolorer" and so the compiler thinks this is a method.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that one! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I m pretty sure that you can t declare method inside constructor. Compiler doesn t even know what there should be so it gives you first obvious error fix that it can give you. Compiler doesn t see big picture what you want to do. It just gives solutions for smallest problem that it encounters.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please add the programming language you are using.